# Extracting two strings from quotations in Java using regex?

Tags: java, regex, extract

I'm new to using patterns and looked everywhere on the internet for an explanation to this problem.

Say I have a string: `String info = "Data I need to extract is 'here' and 'also here'";`

How would I extract the words:

```
here
also here
```

without the single quotes using a pattern?

This is what I have so far...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\').*(?=\')");
```

But it returns ( `here and 'also here` ) minus the brackets, that is just for viewing. It skips over the second piece of data and goes straight to the last quote...

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thank you for your replies everyone! How would it be possible to alter the pattern so that *here* is stored in matcher.group(1) and *also here* is stored in matcher.group(2)? I need these values for different reasons, and splitting them from 1 group seems inefficient...

Answer (score 3):

Try making your regex non-greedy:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=')(.*?)(?=')");
```

EDIT:

This does not work. It gives the following matches:

```
here
 and 
also here
```

This is because the lookahead/lookbehind do not consume the `'`.

To fix this use the regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
```

or even better (& faster):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'");
```

Comment: Would this method return two groups in the matcher that I can access by matcher.group(1) and matcher.group(2)?

Comment: @user656710: Your original regex did not have any groups. I've put the `.*?` in `()`, so both the words will be found in group(1).

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for the reply. As a side note how would this be implemented so that the words are stored in two separate groups?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it to complicated, try

```
Pattern.compile("'([^']+)'");
```

or

```
Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
```

They will both work. Then you can extract the result from the first group `matcher.group(1)` after performing a `matcher.find()`.

Comment: Would there be any way to divide the results into matcher.group(1) and matcher.group(2)?

Comment: @user656710, yes using `'([^']+)'.*?'([^']+)'`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'([\\w\\s]+)'");
    String info = "Data I need to extract is 'here' and 'also here'";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(info);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Here's the printout:-

```
here
also here
```

If you want the data in 2 separate groups, you could do something like this:-

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\s]*?'([\\w\\s]+)'[\\w\\s]*?'([\\w\\s]+)'$");
    String info = "Data I need to extract is 'here' and 'also here'";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(info);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Group 1: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Group 2: " + m.group(2));
    }
```

Here's the printout:

```
Group 1: here
Group 2: also here
```

Comment: This looks good... how would I be able to split the two pieces of data into separate groups?

Comment: I'm not sure why but it seems the pattern wasn't compiled correctly... I did not get any finds/results :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that works, because I ran that code in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using simply the following?

```
'.*?'
```